# How to detect lines using probabilistic hough transform

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform

I am trying to get the coordinates of the line formed by a milling tool blade using `HoughLinesP` (probabilistic hough line transform)in OpenCV, but so far I can't get it to work.

I have tried the following:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.bmp')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 150, 220)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 6, np.pi / 60, 5)

lined = img.copy()

for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[0]:
    cv2.line(lined, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

As you can (barely) see here:
[image: matplotlib image]

The line segment returned by HoughLinesP does not extend for the entire length of the blade.

Here is the Canny edge detection output, and the area of interest that I'm looking at. To me, it seems like the pixels form a straight line. Shouldn't the Hough Transform function return the line segment formed by the blade?

[image]

Does anyone have an idea on how I would improve the detection of the line segment?

Thanks

The original image:
[image: original image]

Comment: I can not understand what is your expected output should look like. Which part of the tool you want to detect?

Comment: View the canny output and see if you have any lines. Then view the hough line output. Always best to view your steps along the way. You many need to adjust the arguments for lower thresholds. Your rho and theta accuracies may be too coarse. See https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html for example.

Comment: Your object does not have a lot of long straight lines. So the hough processing will not find much. As I mentioned above, view the canny and hough images. Perhaps try lowering thresholds and rho, theta increments.

Comment: Hough is to detect straight lines. You have curved lines you want to detect. This will never work.

Comment: @unlut Sorry for not clarifying, I have updated my post to show the area of interest

Comment: @fmw42 I've tried lowering the threshold, but I don't think I can lower it anymore, yet it doesn't work. I have also updated my post to clarify the area that I am talking about.

Comment: @CrisLuengo the part I have highlighted in my edit seems straight enough. Shouldn't this work?

Comment: @Andre, from what I understood, "barely any blade is detected" refers to the red dot in the picture? How is that red dot placed? Because it looks like it is on a blade, to me. The two blades at the left and right border of the tip of the tool, by far, are not a straight line, on the long run, why not shift to CannyEdges at all?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Hough originally was for straight lines, but theory exists for arbitrary shapes as well. The OpenCV implementation and function used by the OP is for straight lines specifically.

Comment: @DaemonPainter Sorry, I want the coordinates of the line segment formed by the edge. When using ```HoughLinesP```, the line segment is incomplete.

Comment: @DaemonPainter: Yes, the Generalized Hough Transform is a nice theoretical concept. Outside of circles and ellipses, I have not seen it applied anywhere. And even with ellipses it is impractical because they have too many parameters. And arbitrary curves cannot be parameterized at all. Though specifically to this case: the curves here can be parameterized. Out of the 4 parameters you’d need, 2 can be determined by other means and fixed for the transform (location and orientation of bit in image), leaving you with a nice 2D transform space (rate of twist and offset for each edge).

Comment: @CrisLuengo The line segment in the canny edge close-up seems straight enough, is there a reason why ```HoughLinesP``` doesn't work for my case?

Comment: Over small enough distances all lines are straight. But the bit of line in the closeup is very short w.r.t. the full image size, and so you’ll get a very small peak in the Hough space. The code is just not designed for this case.

Comment: @CrisLuengo what do you suggest I do for my code? Scan through the horizontal of the image to find a line that most matches?